# Jquery Mobile / Phonegap - closing a pop up

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to show a pop up which will close when touched and also keep the underlying page as it was left because it will have open accordions on it. This works in the browser but wont close on android. I'm using android 2.3, jquery mobile and phonegap.

My code is:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div>
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="true" data-history="true" data-overlay-theme="c" onclick="closePopup();" >
<p>This is a basic popup.<p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
function closePopup(){
    $('#popupBasic').popup('close');
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: try the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6ASSh/ instead of using inline JS.